# Unable to upload file to Orthanc server from C# application

Tags: c#, file-upload, dicom

I am trying to upload a DICOM file to local Orthanc server but I get the error that:

```
Unknown Tag & Data (2d2d,6664) larger (1647393075) than remaining bytes (76) in file, premature end of stream
E0424 16:02:20.786940 FromDcmtkBridge.cpp:1925] Cannot parse an invalid DICOM file (size: 84 bytes)
```

I have wrote the following code to upload the file on the server:

```
DicomFile dicomfile = new DicomFile(dataset);
dicomfile.Save("dicomfile.dcm");

////finally uploading the file to Orthanc
String dcm = File.ReadAllText("./test9signedLimited.dcm");

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "multipart/form-data");
HttpContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

content.Headers.ContentType= new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");

var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost.:18888/instances", content).Result;

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var r = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

**Note** I have tried to upload the same file using POSTMAN and it was successfully uploaded there.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: For your information @E_net4 ContentType is actually the string representing Content-Type header in C#. I actually used Content-Type but it resulted in error then I researched and found out that ContentType is the supported string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not knowing anything about C#, but I see two problems in the code at the moment.

1. You read in the DICOM file from disk, but I don't see any code to actually attach the DICOM data to the POST request. It seems, that You are posting an empty request with only headers.
2. You use `File.ReadAllText` to read the DICOM file from disk, which returns a `String`. This does not seem right, since DICOM is a binary format and converting to it to a string is more than likely to break it. You more likely need a byte array with the DICOM data to attach to the POST request.

Answer (score 1):

Although this answer does not cover a `C#` solution, you have a `python` option that might help you. The [Orthanc Server](https://www.orthanc-server.com/) [1] has a solution for [sending DICOM images](http://book.orthanc-server.com/users/rest.html#sending-dicom-images) to the server. Instructions are as follows.

```
python ImportDicomFiles.py localhost 8042 ~/DICOM/
```

[1] Jodogne, S., 2018. The orthanc ecosystem for medical imaging. Journal of digital imaging, 31(3), pp.341-352.